# Stock Beta through API (Preferably in C#)

Tags: financial, stock, yahoo-finance, google-finance

Anyone know how to get a stock's Beta through an API? (Preferably in C#)

I know it's available on Yahoo/Google/Reuters/Bloomberg when you go to their website, but it seems like none of the YQL / Google Finance stock API / other interfaces support access to this element.

Answer (score 0):

either parse the web page, or use a ready parser like:

http://code.google.com/p/yahoo-finance-managed/